# symfony2 and doctrine and children in where clause

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, entity, parent-child

i tried to select one record with its children as below:

```
$job = $em->getRepository('RaxcidoBaseBundle:Job')->findOneById($id);
```

it will return me an array that has record  and all children as well.
now i want to select this job if has a child with name='test', what is the solution?
i prefer to use docrine functions, not query

these are my entities

```
<?php
...
class Job
{
...
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="JobPrerequisite", mappedBy="job")
 */
protected $prerequisites;
```

and

```
<?php
...
class JobPrerequisite
{
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job", inversedBy="prerequisites")
 * @orm\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $job;

/**
 * @orm\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in these two line :

First find $jobPrerequisite relevant to name = 'test'

```
$jobPrerequisite = $em->getRepository('RaxcidoBaseBundle:JobPrerequisite')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'test'));
```

and then your $job relevant to above  $jobPrerequisite

```
 $job = $em->getRepository('RaxcidoBaseBundle:Job')->findOneBy(array('prerequisites' => $jobPrerequisite));
```